# ifstream file opening issues

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am having a hell of a time trying to open files on a network drive with ifstream.

I can successfully open the file if... I explicitly declare the filename, such as ifstream f("filename.txt").

However, that is the only way I can get the file open, and I need be able to dynamically find the name of that file and open it. Right now I have a string vector of the filenames in a given folder.

I have tried the following as input arguments to the ifstream constructor, to no success.

- converting the string using c_str().
- declaring a char* and assigning the string.cstr() to it.
- same as above, but const char*
- changed the system directory to the folder where the file is, and inputted the filename itself (relative path)

I print out the filename and change to its directory each time before trying to open it, so I know for a fact the filename is 100% correct.

Comment: What does your code actually look like?

Comment: If on Windows, are you remembering to escape your backslashes?

Comment: Make sure you print the filenames with quotes so you spot leading or trailing spaces: they do matter. For example, `std::cout << "name='" << string << "'\n";`

Comment: @paddy: In string variables you don't need to escape backslashes, of course. You only need to escape them while putting them into string literals.

Comment: Yeah, more information, especially a code segment, is going to be really helpful. For example `ifstream f("filename.txt")` will just create a file on your local file system, if it doesn't exist.

Which is also to say, we'd like to see how you're confirming that you're opening the file you expect to be opening.

Comment: @DietmarKühl oh yes, I had overlooked the part that stated the strings are not literals.  I wonder if those filenames contain characters like carriage return or line feed.

Comment: @mHurley `ifstream f("filename.txt")` will *not* create the file if it doesn't exist!  You are thinking of `ofstream`.

Comment: @paddy Yup, good catch.